# How to write this more "Pythonically"

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to write a group of checkboxes (I actually should probably write it as a class, because it is very possible we'll add additional ones)

So far I've got this, but this repeats code and so isn't very efficient. In what ways can I make the code more elegant?

```
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

c1 = Checkbutton(text="Snagit", variable=var1)
c1.pack()

c2 = Checkbutton(text="Camtasia", variable=var2)
c2.pack()

c3 = Checkbutton(text="GotoMeeting", variable=var3)
c3.pack()

app.mainloop()

check1 = var1.get()
check2 = var2.get()
check3 = var3.get()
```

Comment: Outside of using tuple unpacking and combining calls on one line, there's not that much you could do to make it more "Pythonic"...

Comment: `vars = [IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()] ... checks = [v.get() for v in vars]` would be a start....

Comment: Repetition, repetition, repetition - twice is co-incidence, three times means use an array and a loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to use a loop to make this a little better:

```
check_names = ["Snagit", "Camtasia", "GotoMeeting"]
variables = []
for name in check_names:
    variables.append(IntVar())
    Checkbutton(text=name, variable=variables[-1]).pack()

app.mainloop()
checks = [variable.get() for variable in variables]
```

Comment: Yup, this is more like it, though I still have mixed feelings about those repeated `IntVar()`.

Comment: Why are you typing out `IntVar`? That should be in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this solution though the use of `itertools` module might look a bit daunting but I swear learning it is for your own good! :)

```
labels = ("snagit", "camtasia", "gotomeeting")
vars = [IntVar() for _ in labels]
for name, v in itertools.izip(labels, vars):
    Checkbutton(text=name, variable=v).pack()
app.mainloop()
checks = [v.get() for v in vars]
```

Comment: It'd be more readable to use an xrange for `vars`, but this does the job *very nicely*.

Comment: Itertools may be nice for some jobs, but is needlessly complex for this task. Your three lines of code is harder to understand than another answer that uses a simple for loop. For me, zip is like a little speedbump when I read code because I just don't see it or use it very often.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I don't mind the down-vote (assuming it was you; if not please disregard) but I'm pretty sure this boils down to personal preferences. I use itertools module all the time due to its versatile nature and try to avoid "Java"ish stuff in my Python code to the point that more verbose code acts as a "speedbump" for me. Of course, you can surely have a different opinion and I totally respect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
vars = {}
buttons = {}

for text in ('Snagit', 'Camtasia', 'GotoMeeting'):
    vars[text] = IntVar()
    buttons[text] = Checkbutton(text=text, variable=vars[text])
    buttons[text].pack()


app.mainloop()

checks = [var.get() for var in vars.values()]
```

By using `dict`s and `tuple`s, you eliminate repetition. This isn't as sexy as some of the solutions using only generators, but there's no reason to do that here, and I think this is rather more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Accumulate the variables and create the buttons inline:

```
variables = []
for text in ['Snagit', 'Camtasia', 'Gotomeeting']:
    variable = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(text=text, variable=variable).pack()
    variables.append(variable)

app.mainloop()

checks = [variable.get() for variable in variables]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vars = [IntVar() for i in xrange(3)]
buttons = [Checkbutton(text="Snagit", variable=vars[0]),Checkbutton(text="Camtasia", variable=vars[1]),Checkbutton(text="GotoMeeting", variable=vars[2])]
for c in buttons:
  c.pack()

app.mainloop()
check1,check2,check3  = [v.get() for v in vars]
```

I don't know if this is Pythonic, but I think it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: `[c.pack() for c in buttons]` I don't consider list comprehensions with side effects to be very pythonic.

Comment: ok, depends on the view of it. and what pack() does exactly. if it returns a packed c, then it's fine. if you're abusing [] to write a for loop, I don't think this is pythonic. and it looks like you do, because you don't assign a name to the list.

Comment: You're right about that being abusive. I changed it into a loop now.